# How to prompt to change text of an h1 box

Tags: javascript

I would like to change the title of my page, which is in an h1 box.
I know I have to use the onclick function, but I have only ever used this function with buttons. How can I change the title of the page when the mouse clicks the h1 box?

Here is my HTML with JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practice</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'/>
</head>

<script>
function changeTitle() {
        var title = prompt("Change the title:");
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 onclick="changeTitle()">To-Do List</h1>
        <ul class='todo-list'>
            <li class='todo-item'>4L 2% Milk
                <span class='remove'></span></li>
            <li class='todo-item'>Butter, Unsalted
                <span class='remove'></span></li>
            <li class='todo-item'>Dozen Eggs
                <span class='remove'></span></li>
            <li class='todo-item'>Walk the dog
                <span class='remove'></span></li>
            <li class='todo-item'>Cut the lawn
                <span class='remove'></span></li>
            <li class='todo-item'>Laundry
                <span class='remove'></span></li>
            <li class='todo-new'>
                <input id='new-item-text' type='text'/>
                <a id='add-item' href='#'>+</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the content of `h1` on click of `h1`? if so then simply give a id or use some other selector to select the element and add the click handler just as you will do for a button

Comment: Also you need to share the relevant html for us to see

Comment: Document.getElementById('idOfYourH1').innerText = 'what ever you want'. You can call changeTitle with this as a parameter and then you can use set the elements inner text directly.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, you just need to set `innerText` to be the title you get back from `prompt()`. The easiest way to get access to the `h1` is by passing it into `changeTitle()`. When it's clicked, its available as `this`, which we can then use in the function.

```js
function changeTitle(element) {
  var title = prompt("Pick a new title:");
  element.innerText = title;
}
```

```html
<h1 onclick="changeTitle(this)">First Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<h1 id="myTitle">To-Do List</h1>
```

then..

```
function changeTitle() {
  var title = prompt("Change the title:");  
  if(title){
    this.innerText = title
  }  
}            

var el = document.getElementById("myTitle"); 
el.addEventListener("click", changeTitle);
```